# Uploading data to atlas texture in worker thread and sampling from same texture in render thread

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures, sampling

There are 2 OpenGLES2 contexts, that are is same "share group". I know that it's possible to upload texture in worker thread while it's not being used in render thread.
But is it possible to upload portion of data to a region on atlas texture from worker thread and sample from same atlas texture (but from different region, of course)? I've read that rendering to a texture and sampling it will lead to undefined behavior (unless using NV_texture_fence), but it's not actually my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No*, that breaks the [1st and 2nd rules from the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH2-SW5):

> It is your application’s responsibility to manage state changes to OpenGL ES objects when the sharegroup is shared by multiple contexts. Here are the rules:
>
> 1. Your application may access the object across multiple contexts simultaneously **provided the object is not being modified**.
> 2. *While the object is being modified* by commands sent to a context, **the object must not be read or modified on any other context**.
> 3. After an object has been modified, all contexts must rebind the object to see the changes. The contents of the object are undefined if a context references it before binding it.